# Image coming out of overlay in android

Tags: android, crop, zooming

I have done one sample for cropping based on below link

[AndroidCropMoveScaleImage](https://github.com/rameshkec85/AndroidCropMoveScaleImage).

In this sample cropping functionality working good but getting problem with zooming.

problem is when we apply the zoom to the inside of overlay, image moving to the top left corner like shown below.

changes in CropImageView :

Init method() :

mCropOverlayView.setEnabled(false);

then changes the seekbar values to 10.

[image] .

how to avoid this or is there any solution for this?

i tried and googled also for solution but failed.
please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code

Comment: i haven't added much code to that library. update my changes

Comment: when changes the mCropOverlayView.setEnabled(false); then the image listeners will be enabled.